# Combining MergeSort with Insertion sort to make it more efficient

Tags: java, mergesort, insertion-sort

So I have a MergeSort algorithm and I want to combine MergeSort with Insertion sort to reduce the overhead of merging, the question is how? I want to sort the segments using insertion sort and then merge.

```
 public class mergesorttest{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int d[]= {10,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,5,6,7,1};
        mergeSort(d,0,d.length);
        for(int x:d) System.out.print(x+" "); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }

static void mergeSort(int f[],int lb, int ub){
    //termination reached when a segment of size 1 reached -lb+1=ub
    if(lb+1<ub){
        int mid = (lb+ub)/2;
        mergeSort(f,lb,mid);
        mergeSort(f,mid,ub);
        merge(f,lb,mid,ub);
    }
}

static void merge (int f[],int p, int q, int r){
    //p<=q<=r
    int i =p; int j = q; 
    //use temp array to store merged sub-sequence
    int temp[] = new int[r-p]; int t = 0; 
    while(i<q && j<r){
        if(f[i]<=f[j]){
            temp[t] =f[i]; 
            i++;t++;
        }
        else{
            temp[t] = f[j];
            j++;
            t++;
        }

        //tag on remaining sequence
        while(i<q){
            temp[t] = f[i];
            i++;
            t++;

        }
        while(j<r){
            temp[t]=f[j];
            j++;
            t++;
        }
        //copy temp back to f
        i=p;t=0;
        while(t<temp.length){
            f[i]=temp[t];
            i++;
            t++;
        }
        }
}
}
```

---

```
public static void insertion_srt(int array[], int n, int b){
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
  int j = i;
  int B = array[i];
  while ((j > 0) && (array[j-1] > B)){
  array[j] = array[j-1];
  j--;
  }
  array[j] = B;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The merging automatically takes care of sorting the elements. However, one can sort using insertion sort when the list gets below some threshold:

```
static final int THRESHOLD = 10;
static void mergeSort(int f[],int lb, int ub){
    if (ub - lb <= THRESHOLD)
        insertionSort(f, lb, ub);
    else
    {
        int mid = (lb+ub)/2;
        mergeSort(f,lb,mid);
        mergeSort(f,mid,ub);
        merge(f,lb,mid,ub);
    }
}
```

Doing anything other than this (except playing around with the threshold a little) will **increase** the time taken by merge sort.

Although merge sort is O(n log n) and insertion sort is O(n<sup>2</sup>), insertion sort has better constants and is thus faster on very small arrays. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622015/why-should-insertion-sort-be-used-after-threshold-crossover-in-merge-sort), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736920/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-insertion-sort), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643377/why-is-insertion-sort-faster-than-quick-sort-and-bubble-sort-for-small-cases) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101546/why-is-insertion-sort-better-than-quick-sort-for-small-list-of-elements) are a few related questions I found.

Comment: This is a good answer, though it helps to go a little bit into the theory of Big O and explain best case/worst case/average case.

Comment: it may be worth mentioning that this is exactly how the built in JDK sort works - for arrays < 7 it does an insertion sort, for > 7 it does a mergesort.

Comment: I thought `Collections.sort()` used quicksort for larger collections.

Comment: @bdares [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) + [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) on objects = mergesort. [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])) on primitives = quicksort

Comment: Woah that's cool information, guys! Are there links to the relevant source available?

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions I provided links in my previous comment. You can also probably check the Java source.

Comment: I guess what I was asking is if the source for Arrays.sort() and Collections.sort() is available at a non "download the jdk and go into the included files" internet URL for easy lookup, or if the way you came up with this information was by doing exactly that.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions I just checked the links I provided, it says which algorithm it uses. But, if you want - [Collections source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/Collections.java.html), [Arrays source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/Arrays.java.html). Note that if you have the JDK and a proper IDE (NetBeans), opening the source is as easy as Ctrl+Click.

Comment: @Dukeling Why have you taken mid in mergeSort(f,mid,ub) instead of (mid+1)?

Answer (score 5):

```
public static final int K = 5;

public static void insertionSort(int A[], int p, int q) {
    for (int i = p; i < q; i++) {
        int tempVal = A[i + 1];
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j > p && A[j - 1] > tempVal) {
            A[j] = A[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        A[j] = tempVal;
    }
    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, p, q +1);
    Arrays.stream(temp).forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
    System.out.println();
}

public static void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    int[] LA = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, p, q +1);
    int[] RA = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, q+1, r +1);
    int RIDX = 0;
    int LIDX = 0;
    for (int i = p; i < r - p + 1; i++) {
        if (RIDX == n2) {
            A[i] = LA[LIDX];
            LIDX++;
        } else if (LIDX == n1) {
            A[i] = RA[RIDX];
            RIDX++;
        } else if (RA[RIDX] > LA[LIDX]) {
            A[i] = LA[LIDX];
            LIDX++;
        } else {
            A[i] = RA[RIDX];
            RIDX++;
        }
    }
}

public static void sort(int A[], int p, int r) {
    if (r - p > K) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        sort(A, p, q);
        sort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    } else {
        insertionSort(A, p, r);
    }
}

public static void main(String string[]) {
    int[] A = { 2, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9 };
    sort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
    Arrays.stream(A).forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
}
```